# Explanation on how the minus/except operator works

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how the minus/except operator works. 
Somehow I cannot find anything useful on the web. The "minus" operator is used to return all rows in the first statement that are not part of the second statement. But how exactly does it manage to do this?

Can someone please provide me how this is done "step by step"?

Comment: Go here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Comment: If the question is asking how the db engine does this, review the explain plan.  If the question is how do you syntactically do this... see @JoeTaras comment.

Comment: Hey Joe, that does not help. It still just says what the outcome of the minus operation is, but not how it works step by step.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Note:** The following answer is true for Oracle. See [The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm#i2054381)

My SQL has only UNION and UNION ALL. Results for INTERSECT and MINUS can be got using IN and NOT IN. See [Union, Difference, Intersection, and Division in MySQL](http://faculty.utpa.edu/chebotkoa/main/teaching/csci4333fall2013/slides/MySQL-set-operators.pdf) [PDF]

In SQL Server, MINUS is called EXCEPT. See [Set Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848745.aspx)

---

I am surprised you are unable to find anything related to this on the Web. MINUS is a set operation in SQL, others include `UNION`, `UNION ALL` and `INTERSECT`.

This is what they do:

**Sample Data**:

**`EMPLOYEE`**

```
ID  NAME  SALARY  AGE
 1  Alice  5000    23
 2  Joe    1000    25
 3  Raj    2000    28
 4  Pam    1500    32
```

**UNION**:

[image: Union]

Returns results from SQL 1 combiled with Results from SQL 2, after removing duplicates. A variation is `UNION ALL` that does not remove duplicates. `UNION ALL` has better performance because it does not do the sort and remove duplication (internal) step. Union all is useful when the results of two SQLs being used are mutually exclusive.

```
select * from employee where salary > 1000
union
select * from employee where age > 25
```

returns all employees that are 25 years old or more or have a salary > 1000 (satisfy **either** condition)

```
ID  NAME  SALARY  AGE
 1  Alice  5000    23
 3  Raj    2000    28
 4  Pam    1500    32
```

Using `UNION ALL` in the above case returns record for Raj twice because UNION ALL does not remove duplicates.

```
select * from employee where salary > 1000
union all
select * from employee where age > 25


ID  NAME  SALARY  AGE
 1  Alice  5000    23
 3  Raj    2000    28
 4  Pam    1500    32
 3  Raj    2000    28
```

**INTERSECT**:

[image: Intersect]

Returns only common records between the result sets.

```
select * from employee where salary > 1000
intersect
select * from employee where age > 25
```

returns only those records that satisfy **both** conditions: Have salary > 1000 AND are over 25.

```
ID  NAME  SALARY  AGE
 3  Raj    2000    28
 4  Pam    1500    32
```

**MINUS**:
Returns records from SQL 1 after removing results from SQL 2:

[image: Minus]

```
select * from employee where salary > 1000
intersect
select * from employee where age > 25
```

returns all those employees that have a salary > 1000 after removing employees that are more than 25 years of age:

```
ID  NAME  SALARY  AGE
 1  Alice  5000    23
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give you a clue !

```
create table #t(id int)
insert into #t values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

create table #t2(id1 int)
insert into #t2 values(2),(5),(6)

select * from #t except select * from #t2

select id from #t left join #t2 on #t.id=#t2.id1 where #t2.id1 is null
```

## [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17535)

IN set theory

say `A={A,B,C,D}` ,`B={B,X,Y,Z}`

so `A-B={A,C,D}` -- which is a `left join` in `sql`

[image]

Comment: To reformulate my question. I know how except/minus works logically. I am more interested in how those operators are executed internally by the database. Does it just compare every row from Set A with every row from set B to get my result?

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

```
create table U
( x int not null primary key );
insert into U (x) values (1),(2),(3);

create table V
( y int not null primary key );
insert into U (x) values (3),(4);
```

Now `U - V = { 1, 2 }`

`U - V` can be expressed as:

All tupels in U that does not exist in V, i.e.

```
select x 
from U
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from V
    where V.y = U.x
);
```

In the same way `V - U = { 4 }`

Did that clarify?